# Easy way to initialize new ember-data model from json data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I wan't to get initial data for a new model from server, eg. from url /users/new.json which responds:

```
{"user":
  {
    "default_value1": "foo", 
    "default_value2": "bar",
    "embedded_foo": [{"default_value3": "baz"}]
  }
}
```

User model:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  embeddedFoo: DS.hasMany('App.EmbeddedFoo'),
  defaultValue1: DS.attr('string'),
  defaultValue2: DS.attr('string')
})
```

There is a lot more values, so is there some way to initialize a new record using existing ember-data mappings?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This came from another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15420204/1157494), but the basic gist is:

```
var userData = {"user":
  [{
    "id": 1,
    "default_value1": "foo", 
    "default_value2": "bar",
    "embedded_foo": [{"default_value3": "baz"}]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "default_value1": "bang", 
    "default_value2": "biff",
    "embedded_foo": [{"default_value3": "boop"}]
  }]
}

App.Store = DS.Store.create({
  revision: 11
});

App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  embeddedFoo: DS.hasMany('App.EmbeddedFoo'),
  defaultValue1: DS.attr('string'),
  defaultValue2: DS.attr('string')
})

App.Store.loadMany(App.User, [1,2], userData);
```

More details on `DS.Store.loadMany`: [definition](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L1616) or [tests](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/tests/unit/store_test.js#L211).

Comment: That is for loading existing data. It would be ok if I can do it without ids and change the record state as new.