# Bootstrapping data in ember.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

What's the best way to bootstrap data for an emberjs app on page load. I know it will most likely get the data from either a data-for attribute or data within a hidden div, but where in the emberjs app lifecycle would this go?

Comment: could you explain the "user comes back" part a little more in depth? ie -are you using local storage or cookies or something else in the browser that is available right away (to show some content) before the $.ajax stuff happens?

Comment: The "user comes back" implies that there is a session. So I would have some json embedded into the html that the ember app would use to bootstrap (along with other information, not just the user). What I'm trying to figure out is the best place in the ember app lifecycle to grab the data from the html and use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few different kinds of data that you might be loading.  I have been using `ember-data` models along with `DS.FixtureAdapter` (for static data) or the `DS.RESTAdapter` (for dynamic data.

This is a small example using fixtures:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 11,
  adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
});

App.Page = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Page.FIXTURES = [{
    id: 1,
    title: "Test Title #1"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    title: "Random Title #2"
  }];
```

In my (smallish) apps I am just loading the fixture data directly after defining the store and models.  This works well for simple one to one associations (think a static listing of types or categories).  When using non fixture type data it is just specified as the `model` attribute on the route, and is loaded up when needed.

**Update**

To pre-load initial data (e.g. initial page state like loggedIn) on page load you could use `DS.Store#load`:

```
Store = DS.Store.create({
  revision: 11
});

Page = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string')
});

Store.load(Page, {id: 1, title: 'Wow Cool Title'});

Store.find(Page, 1).get('title') //=> 'Wow Cool Title'
```

Comment: I'm using the RESTAdapter. What I'm trying to get at is how to load data that I have on the page when I render everything initially. So for instance I have a current user I want to keep track of, and I want to bootstrap the current user on page load (say the user closes the page and comes back later).

Comment: I think that will work. Do you know if Store.load takes in arrays? If not I suppose I could just loop over the embedded data and do a Store load for each.

Comment: Yes, you can load more than one record at a time with `DS.Store.loadMany` (see the definition [here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L1616) and a few tests [here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/tests/unit/store_test.js#L211).